# Write to a text field and simultaneously copy to another textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textfield with different ids. what I want to achieve is that when I write to textfield1 that content is immediately copied to the second one and if I edit the second one the first one remains unchanged, but also if I go back to first one and edit it, the content is just appended to the second one.

```
<input type="text" name="field1" id="f1" />
<input type="text" name="field2" id="f2" />
```

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#f1").keyup(function(){
           $('#f2').val($('#f1').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: content upended to second one or get replaced with first one?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#f1").keypress(function (e) {
        var val = $('#f2').val();
        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
        $('#f2').val(val+(String.fromCharCode(code)));
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/9tpWx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#f1").keyup(function(){
        var f2Text = $('#f2').val() + $(this).val();
        $('#f2').val(f2Text );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the Angular JS which is more efficient and easy to use.

[AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)

Angular JS will help you to develop SPA(Single Page Application).